# Proper way to pass username/password to SmtpClient (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, smtpclient, configuration-management

The question is too simple, but still appreciate the short answer. I would like the `SmtpClient` to fetch username/password from the `App.config` file. From the MSDN/schema I've figured out that the proper file (excerpt) should look like:

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="foo@bar.com">
        <network
          host="mail.bar.com"
          port="25"
          userName="foouser"
          password="barpassword"
        />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

I am trying to find the proper API to call, when initializing `SmtpClient` state, so that mail and password will be nicely fetched from the XML:

```
  var client = new SmtpClient( ... ); // how to fetch the servername?
  client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential( ... , ... ); // how to fetch user/pass
  client.Send(message);
```

Is there a proper/dedicated way to fetch `servername`, `user`, `password` or should I just call the "regular" API like `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["server"]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing special is needed, just initialize and send :)

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Send(mymessagehere);
```

That is all, it will pull from the config.

Comment: thanks a lot! I've suspected it might be simple :) Read the MSDN, looked for something similar, but couldn't find. Better luck next time :)

Comment: I'll accept the answer in 6 minutes, the system says that waiting is important.